# local vs remote path definitions

Tags: php, path, directory

Say I used `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` to get my `ROOT` path, at which point we get something along the lines of `/home/a8122625/public_html/` if I want to use this in script to check whether or not the file exists thats fine, but if I print the `ROOT` to a, say, image folder so that I can build an image src using it. I will get something along the lines of `<img src="/home/a8122625/public_html/images/someimage.jpg">` which comes out with a bad location (for obvious reasons).

I primarily want to define my roots using the aformentioned method since its compatable with windows, so I can develop locally, and have the same path definitions remotely. However for images, I have ended up seeing if user is on localhost or not, and then outputting the proper root as per the requirements of windows or apache.

Is there an all-encompassing way of defining directories as such that I can have the same functionality locally and remotely? What am I doing wrong?

I have found similar questions on stack, however none of which fully address the solution in an all-encompassing manner. I feel as though this question is one that ought to be addressed, and some have more interesting solutions than I can come up with.

Comment: You mean you want to reference local files via the file protocol, so accessing the local file system?

Comment: Why don't you simply use relative paths? `<img src="images/someimage.jpg">`? This works independent of the actual location of the sites root position.

Comment: thats what ive ended up doing. but i was wondering if someone had a 'fix' for this, or another creative way of doing it

Comment: Why a fix? What for? Relative paths are a very elegant and clean solution!

Comment: The URL path is rather the real file system path without the document root path prefix.

Answer (score 1):

HTML references are typically relative to the DOCUMENT_ROOT / webserver base url.

File paths in PHP relate to the server root / physical directory structure, thus using `{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}` helps with parity.